# Convert video to exactly the same stream type of other video in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Maybe this is a silly question, didn't manage to find a clear answer anywhere.

I need to use ffmpeg to convert a given video to exactly the same format another video has, including bitrate, video and audio codecs... everything. The goal is to concat both videos into a single file, independently of the original formats.

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to build a complex command line input specifying all parameters?

The concat demuxer is not enough... maybe something with filter_complex?

Thanks and sorry for the bother.

Comment: I have exact the same problem. Adding `-map_metadata 0` before output string should copy all metadata from input to output, but it doesn't seems to work.